# How to get hotel price and redirect url from Sabre API

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use Sabre API in my app i am getting all the details from Sabre API but two important field is missing which are price and redirect url so how can i get these data from Sabre API any body help thanks in advance.

```
$url = "https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v1.0.0/lists/utilities/geosearch/locations?mode=geosearch";
$response = sabreApiCall($url, $data_array);
$results = json_decode($response);
```

Comment: Did you check the document? you can only get what the API provides.

Comment: i have checked docs bro so what is missing

Comment: any body have and idia